# Delete request works but doesn't delete from database

Tags: mongoose, findby

when i'm trying to delete an item by FindByIdAndDelete it doesn't delete anything.
when i make the delete request in postman i don't get no errors just the item's in the db.
happens the same with my put request.

that's my code:

```js
router.delete("/", (req, res) => {
  Appointment.find({}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json();
    } else {
      return res.json(data);
    }
  });
});

router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  Appointment.findByIdAndDelete(id, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json();
    } else {
      return res.json(data);
    }
  });
});
```

that's the body i put in my request :

```
{
"id": "5e3ef4950e1b4027201e73bf"
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findByIdAndDelete` doesn't throw exception when it doesn't find the document to be deleted. You need to check if data is null or not.

Also your first route must be a GET route instead of DELETE.

```js
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Appointment.find({}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json();
    } else {
      return res.json(data);
    }
  });
});

router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  Appointment.findByIdAndDelete(id, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json();
    } else {
      if (data) {
        return res.json(data);
      } else {
        return res.status(400).send("Document not found, check id");
      }
    }
  });
});
```